# dividing row in 4 columns using css

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and the code which i am sharing is for footer part of the page.

```
<div id="footerPage"> 
<div id="footerPageId">
    <div  id="footerLeft">
    <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>                   
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </div>
    <div  id="footerCenter">
    <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>                   
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    </ul> 
    </div>
    <div id="partnerWithUs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Partner With Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div id="followUs">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Linkedin</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>           

</div>
```

The styling i gave is

```
    li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.imageDiv {
    background-color: #497DB9;
    display: block;
    width: 1350px;
    height: 70px;
}
.overlap1 {
    height:1022px;
    background-color:white;
    width:1300px;
}
.overlap {
    top: -50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 1000px;
    height:1100px;
}
#footerPage {
    background: #497DB9;
    margin-top: 80px;
    width:100%;
    height:190px;
}
#footerPageId {
    margin-left:129px;
    width:100%;
}
#footerLeft {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height:200px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
#footercenter {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height:200px;
}
#partnerWithus {
    width: 20%;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#followUs {
    width: 20%;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#footerPageId ul>li>a {
    color:white
}
#followUs ul>li>a {
    color:white
}
#partnerWithUs a {
    color:white;
}
```

There are two issues in below output

1)There is some blank space below footer
2) Footer is divided in four columns,div texts are not aligned. For eg , first column "sitemap text" has some space between top of the div(where blue color starts) and first line of that column. While second column there is no space at all.Similarly, third column(partner with us) div has lots of space.
Please visit below URL for entire code
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=Rij7fF1KgWnOmGtJ

[image]

Comment: It probably has something to do with `vertical-align`. I think the default is `vertical-align: baseline`, which is why your columns are aligned at the bottom. Try `vertical-align: top` on your columns.

Comment: thanks,vertical-align top works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give     `vertical-align: top;` to all of your footer divs. And remove `margin-top:-10px` from first div. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: glad to know it help ;)